# Gradle build fails with duplicates when adding google-api-client

Tags: android, gradle, google-api-client

I am adding code to my project which requires google-api-client, when I add it via the gradle dependency, I get a duplicate error.

Here is the gradle dependency list

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
    // compile project(':showcaseView')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':SwipeMenuListView')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'
    compile files('libs/tape-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-photos-meta-2.0.jar')

    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    // compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0'
    // compile files('libs/android-oauth-client-0.4.5.jar')
}
```

Here is the error that I receive

```
Execution failed for task ':FloomIt:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/collect/package-info.class
```

If I remove the google-api-client line from the dependency list, the error goes away.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `com.google.api-client:google-api-client` depends on `com.google.guava:guava-jdk5` but `com.google.gdata:core` depends on `com.google.guava:guava`. The JDK5 split is unfortunate.

Gradle allows you to override dependencies. Try replacing the gdata dependency with something like:

```
compile('com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
```

Comment: In general, is there a way to see what modules are inside libraries? Thanks.

Comment: `gradle dependencies --configuration compile` can be done on a project-by-project basis (not from a root project). You can also view some information at http://search.maven.org in the pom.xml, but that isn't as readable.